# tab-width and <lang>-indent-offset difference

Tags: tabs

I've setup the indentation for tabs in Rust to be 2 whitespaces. That's what I want. And in my config it looks like this:

```
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
    (setq tab-width 2)
    (setq rust-indent-offset 2)))
```

What's the difference between `tab-width` and `rust-indent-offset` or `<lang>-indent-offset`?

Answer (score 1):

`tab-width` is the width used to *display* a TAB character. It also has an effect when `indent-tabs-mode` is non-nil, in which case Emacs uses `tab-width` to decide when to replace so many spaces with one TAB.

`ruby-indent-offset` and similar variables control by how many spaces to indent.